# No power to the fuel pump

Tags: toyota, fuse, cranks-wont-run, fuel-pump, isis

I have a 2006 Toyota Isis and it had a problem where it idled well, but when you press gas the engine started to stall and when you lift your feet then it idled well again.  I took it to have it scanned and they said to replace the fuel regulator sensor. I replaced the fuel regulator sensor, but after I put things back together, it just cranks but won't start.

I measured voltage at fuel pump and there was no power at fuel pump. So I looked for the fuse and relay but couldn’t find it.  Where's the fuel pump fuse on my '06 Isis?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I cannot find an image for it, but the fuel pump fuse is usually located in the underhood fuse panel. Again, I've got no reference for this, but it's where it's at in most cars. As far as the fuel regulator sensor, try and put the old one back and see if it makes any difference for it starting. See if you can get back to jump street. It may be the new sensor which is causing the issue.

Comment: I have the same year isis and I have your second problem, crank but wont start, not getting any power to the gas pump, all the fuses seem to be working, did u get a fix for your problem?

Comment: There are typically two fuse boxes. One in the passenger compartment, possibly near the passenger footwell or kick panel trim. The other will be in the engine bay. Each should have a diagram listing fuses and their locations on the box lid or cover.

Comment: The fuse box in the engine bay, have a diagram in the cover, the one on the inside behind glove box doesn't have a diagram

Comment: Your fuel pump relay is almost certainly in the engine bay fuse box. The interior box is typically for BCM functions. Windows, wipers, heated massaging seats, etc.

Answer (score -1):

[image: inside fuse box] that's the inside fuse box , found that online but for a different Toyota vehicle but everything there is exactly the same on my toyota isis

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. While your contributions are appreciated, this really doesn't answer the question at large. Please take [The Tour](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through the [Help Center](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help) to better understand how StackExchange works and how to answer a question.